# How to connect to the express development server using adb reverse?

Tags: android, react-native, express, android-studio, adb

I'm currently testing my react-native/express app following this guide:

- https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

I have installed Android Studio following React-Native instructions and everything works well. I run the "npm run android" from a bash shell and in another one I run my express's server.

Then, when I try to use my phone connected to my laptop by USB, I can run the React-Native front-end inside my phone but I can't connect to the development server. I run the command "$ adb -s  reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081" and it seems that nothing happens. My backend server is running at 4000 port and React-Native seems to use the port 8081 I tried to connect to "$ adb -s  reverse tcp:8081 tcp:4000" as well.

I've already tried "Method 1: Using adb reverse (recommended)" still remaining try to use the other method.

Edit:

Still getting "Error: [TypeError: Network request failed]" after adding Network Security Configuration file and the attribute at the manifest inside debug folder.

I left a repo that's a minimal reproducible example:

- git clone https://github.com/Jona-md/rn-express-ex.git

Answer (score 0):

First, get the local IP of the machine you're running the test server on. In my case it's `192.168.1.4`.

Edit

`android/app/src/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

and, using the format of the existing security rules, add the local IP of your server inside the `domain-config` tag. Example finished version below (you should only need the line after the comment).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
        <!-- New line, replace my IP with yours -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.4</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

You should now be able to send to your equivalent of `192.168.1.4:4000` (remember to include the port number in the request!).